# How add two registers at the same time in different domains?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two domains: Purchases and Costs. The first one manages the purchases from providers, and the second one manages the costs of the company.

The costs can be for many reasons, not only because of purchases. For example, salaries of employees. In this case, I don’t have an invoice like when I purchase a product from a provider. Instead, I have to create a record in the Costs domain for the employee’s salary.

Purchases are considered a cost, so I would like to create a record in Costs with the total purchase amount. This way, I can analyze the total costs. I wouldn’t need to get data from Purchases, from Costs, or perhaps from other domains.

In the case of salaries of employees, I could use the same logic and create a record in Costs with the salary. However, we are not managing the salaries, at least for the moment.

In my case, I have two domains, two repositories, and two application layers: one for Purchases and another for Costs.

But here is my problem: how to implement this use case? I need to ensure that when I create a purchase, I will create the cost too. I need a transaction. How can I do that?

One solution would be to create a higher repository that uses both repositories. This higher repository would be used by the application layer. In this case, the domains are isolated because they are persistence-agnostic, so it may not matter if there is a higher repository that is used by the application layer.

However, this solution has a problem: it is hard to add new costs. For example, if we start to manage the salaries of the employees, I would need to add the employees to the higher repository.

Another option could be not to create the cost line when I create the purchase. But in this case, to get all the costs in a period of time, I have to do a query to get the purchases, another query to get the costs, calculate the partial costs, and then sum them. It is more work and requires more queries to the database. The good point is that adding the record is simpler, just a CRUD action.

It is also possible to add new kinds of costs, for example, adding salaries of employees. But in this case, to get the total costs, I would have to modify the code that gets all the costs. At least it is a query, not adding data, so it is easier to ensure the consistency of the data.

So, in summary, I would like to know if it is a good idea to create a record in another domain when I create a record in another. If it is a possible solution, how to implement it? If not, what alternatives could be better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Domain events* are a convenient way to go in these scenarios. In DDD aggregate roots are the primary units of transaction. Whenever multiple aggregate roots are involved in the same transaction, domain events are used to communicate between them: an aggregate root raises a domain event that maybe of interest to other aggregate roots; the interested aggregate roots have their subscribers registered at the beginning of the transaction. It ensures decoupling between aggregate roots while achieving business goals. See Vaughn Vernon's book for a more extensive coverage of domain events.

In your situation, the aggregate roots in the *purchase* domain may raise a domain event containing necessary context for cost processing and the *cost* domain may subscribe to that event. The subscriber may be either a *domain service* (if some heavy rule checking is involved) or even a repository method (if it is a simple persistence). Upon any purchase event, the listener may create costs and persist them using its own repositories if the event demands that. It should be obvious how you may process events in other domains that may incur a cost (e.g. employee salaries) the same way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the purchase persist the purchase and then send an event to notify cost domain. Then the cost domain persist the data. But couldn't this lead to unconsistent state? If the purchase can be persisted but when the cost tries to persist the data and there is a problem.

Comment: Consistency depends on _how the cost domain subscribes_ to the other domains' events. If the subscription is _asynchronous_, the system state will be _eventually consistent_. Otherwise, if the subscription is synchronous (happens within the same transaction), then the system state will be consistent upon transaction. You have to design your subscription according to your desire.

Comment: Why to use domain events? I mean, I could have repository with one context, that is used to persists the data for the new purchase and the new cost. This repository maps the needed entities from Purchase domain and Cost domain. Then, the method in the application layer use this repository, call the method from purchase entity to create the purchase, then call the method in the cost domain to create the domain and finally save the changes. All is in a transaction, both domains are persistance ignorance and I don't need to implement messengers neither other this. I think it is simplier.

Comment: Domain events give you a cleaner separation between domains (_bounded contexts_). If I didn't get it wrong, as per your proposal, both your application layer and the repository you are proposing overlap two different bounded contexts (purchase and cost). You could have avoided that with domain events. Implementing domain event subscribers within the same transaction is not difficult at all. You can do that without third party, general purpose message brokers.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. But if I don't misunderstand DDD, bounded context are domain terminology, and it is persistant / repository igonarece. In my case, I have the two domain separated, they don't interact directly, but is the repository who use both domains to ensure the transaction. Also, if i use domain events, in some place I have to set the cost entities to be subscribed to the purchase events. Where should I do that? In the application layer? If it this is the place, is in the application layer where I call first the purchase method and later the cost event.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your question: application services and domain services in a bounded context use repositories to fetch aggregates and persist them. Like the domain model, domain services, and application services, repositories are also part of a bounded context, but the technical aspects involved within them (e.g. querying a database) are not.

Comment: Regarding the second part: yes, you can register your cost domain subscriber at the purchase domain application service just before the actual transaction begins. The cost subscriber (which can either be a domain service or repository method in the cost domain) performs the cost operations and persists the cost aggregate; purchase domain has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I have another doubt. If I register the cost subscriber in the purchase domain, the purchase domain has to have a reference to the cost project. Is  this correct? If I am not wrong, a domain shouldn't have any reference to another projects, because it is the core.